# Many to many relationship with mocking

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So I have two entities (with a many to many relationship) here they are :

```
public class Tag
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Video> Videos { get; set; }
}

public class Video
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string EmbedSource { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

With two repositories :

```
   public interface ITagsRepository
    {
        IQueryable<Tag> GetTags { get; }
    }

public interface IVideosRepository
{
     IQueryable<Video> GetVideos { get; }
}
```

Now I'm trying to mock them in my ninject controller, unfortunately as a beginner I've a problem, as each of my entity need the other, I can't mock them, ironically it seems like I fall in a infinite loop :

```
private void AddBindings()
    {
      Mock<IVideosRepository>  mock = new Mock<IVideosRepository>();
        mock.Setup(m => m.GetVideos).Returns(new List<Video>
        {
            new Video {EmbedSource = "embedcode", ID = 1, Tags = new Tag {ID = 0, Name = "testtestest", Video = new Video ... etc etc}
        })
    }
```

I'm looking for a faster/cleaner way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your entities before setting the Mock:

```
var video1 = new Video {EmbedSource = "embedcode", ID = 1};
var video2 ...
var tag1 = new Tag {ID = 0, Name = "testtestest"};
var tag2 ...
video1.Tags = new List<Tag> { tag1, tag2 };
tag1.Videos = new List<Video> { video1, video2};

Mock<IVideosRepository>  mock = new Mock<IVideosRepository>();
  mock.Setup(m => m.GetVideos).Returns(new List<Video>
  {
    video1, video2
  })
```